# MySQL COUNT and IFNULL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

I have tables like this:
[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/172726/1)

I'm trying to count how many products are in each category

```
SELECT `category_id`, `category_name`, IFNULL(count(*),0) cat_stat 
FROM 
    `product_to_categories`
NATURAL JOIN 
    `categories`
GROUP BY `category_id`
```

it is almost working except IFNULL part.

I recieve:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| category_id | category_name | cat_stat |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 1           | category1     | 5        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 2           | category2     | 5        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 3           | category3     | 6        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 5           | category5     | 4        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

but i would also like to get null results:

```
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| category_id | category_name | cat_stat |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 1           | category1     | 5        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 2           | category2     | 5        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 3           | category3     | 6        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 4           | category4     | 0        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
| 5           | category5     | 4        |
+-------------+---------------+----------+
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. NATURAL JOIN == NATURAL INNER JOIN whereas you need OUTER JOIN.
2. Base table is `categories`, so it must be mentioned first (NATURAL LEFT JOIN takes the values for common columns from the most left table).
3. You must count definite column, not common column or total rows amount (they will give 1, not 0).

```sql
SELECT `category_id`, 
       `category_name`, 
       COUNT(`product_to_categories`.`category_id`) cat_stat 
FROM `categories`
NATURAL LEFT JOIN `product_to_categories`
GROUP BY `category_id`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for explanations! Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can start from `categories`, then bring the products mapping table with `left join`, and finally aggregate, counting on a column from the mapping table.

```
select category_id, c.category_name, count(pc.category_id) cat_stat 
from categories c
left join product_to_categories pc using(category_id)
group by category_id
```

No need for `ifnull()`: `count()` never returns a `null` value.